# Why the 'Simple Deform' modifier bending my object on the wrong axis?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to bend this simple object, a cube and I was following a Youtube tutorial on how to do it and I performed each and every step and it doesn't seem to work for me. I don't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help please?

Steps.

1. Create a cube
2. Scale it along Y-axis
3. Added several loop cuts
4. Created an Empty
5. Added the Simple Deform modifier to the cube
6. Selected Bend
7. Set the Axis, Origin to empty

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgBDV.png)

[image: Loop cuts]

Comment: by default the object will bend on its Z axis, you need to make sure that the rotation has been applied though. And if you give the Simple Deform an other Axis Origin, the object will bend according to this second object axis, so you may need to rotate the empty.

Comment: @moonboots I added rotation of 90 degrees along Z-axis to the empty and it seems to work. Weird that they did not mention this on the tutorial. Thanks (:

Comment: create another cube instead of empty ... working good with me

Answer (score 4):

By default, with the *Simple Deform* modifier, in *Bend* mode, the object will bend on its Z axis. So if your object bends in a unexpected way, it must be because you have rotated it in *Object* mode, and its Z axis is not aligned with the global Z axis anymore. In that case you may want to apply the rotation with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

If you give the *Simple Deform* another *Axis Origin*, like for example an **Empty**, the object will bend according to this second object's Z axis. So same thing, if your object bends in a unexpected way, rotate your empty the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.79, simple deform modifier will bend around Z axis and with a **bending center on the Y axis**.

We can see it here:

- On left, the way the mesh is subdivided
- Center: the center is on the y axis and the modifier try to bend around Z but this is not where the mesh has enough geometry (and is expected) to bend.
- Right: the empty is rotated indicating the Y axis is on the right

[image]

The center is at 'mesh width divided by the angle in radians'.

Using 2.80 the axis which has the role of the Z axis in 2.79 can be changed using the modifier parameters panel.