# How to make my "Simple Deform" mesh bend the other way

Tags: modeling, modifiers, surface-deform

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

i'm trying to make this selected mesh bend along the face horizontally instead of vertically, something similar to image 3 but sideways, how can i do it?

It looks like a sad worm here, lol

Comment: There's a complete tutorial on all the settings for that modifier [here](https://youtu.be/KgM-nWTHAJU). There's also this posting here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143190/why-the-simple-deform-modifier-bending-my-object-on-the-wrong-axis?rq=1

Comment: The sad worm... heartbreaking +1

Comment: Sad worm indeed, lol. Also tnx for the link

Answer (score 3):

The deformation is calculated in the *local* coordinate space. Please note that an object's local axes may differ from the global axes. By default, objects bend along their Z-axis. If your object is rotated in any way, make sure that the Z-axis is pointing up. You can apply the rotation by pressing `CTRL` `A` on your keyboard.

Alternatively, you can check the direction of your object's local Z-axis. To do this, select your object and in the upper-right corner select `Transform` > `Affect only` > `Origins`.

[image]

Then, rotate the origin so that the Z axis points upwards and aligns with the global Z axis. Make sure to deactivate the `Transform`>`Affect only`>`Origins` option once you're finished.

[image]

Here is the Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much dude! It works and I got through! :D